# The title in the tumblr theme I'm desigining won't respond to any color codes

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm designing a tumblr theme and am in the very early stages. Right now I only have the code for a functioning sidebar. I'm trying to format the title, but it won't respond to any code meant to change its color. I know that I've formatted my code correctly because the title responds to changes in its font size. Does anyone know what the issue is? Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="color:Background" content="#cccccc" />
<meta name="color:Primary Color" content="#03999b" />
<meta name="color:Secondary Color" content="#4cc3c5" />


<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="altertnate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/>




<style type="text/css">

/************
CSS
************/

#sidebar 
{
width: 100%; 
height: 150px;
background-color: #000;
position: static;
z-index: 10;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}


#sidebar .title
{
font-size: 40px;
text-align: center;
padding:10px;

}
#sidebar. title a
{

}


#sidebar .title a:hover
{
color: {color:Secondary Color};
}

#sidebar .description {
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  line-height:100%;
}


#sidebar .links {
font: {color:Primary Color};
    color: white;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 7px;
    margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 100%;

}

#sidebar .links a {
text-decoration:none;
color: white;
}

#sidebar .links:hover {
color: {color:Secondary Color};
}
</style>  

</head>

<body>
<!--HTML area-->

<div id="sidebar">
<div class="title"><a href="/">{Title}</a></div>
<div class="description">{Description}</div>
<div class="links">
<a href="/">index</a>
<a href="/ask">message</a>
<a href="/submit">submit</a>
<a href="/archive">archive</a>
</div>
</div> <!--sidebar-->
```

Comment: try to debug using firebug to see the result CSS

Comment: I don't see where you are defining the color of the title. Note also that you have an empty `#sidebar. title a` where the `.` is not correctly placed (should be after the space, not before).

Comment: I had deleted the code when it wouldn't work out of frustration, just to see what would happen. No change.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what colour option you are trying to use, but the following should work.

```
.title {
  color: {color:Primary Color};
}
title a {
  color: inherit;
}
.title a:hover {
  color: {color:Secondary Color};
}
```